# Will Multiple CDN Speed Up Page Load

Tags: cdn

I noticed DJI Store website uses multiple CDN domains to server static elements.

Web page:
https://store.dji.com/?site=brandsite&from=nav

CDNs:

https://asset2.djicdn.com/assets/v2/common/14292283_1302296159810439_4324228009709332653_n.jpg
https://asset4.djicdn.com/assets/v2/build/app-0f0a05d6b0cd030cf68ca92e67816241.css
https://product2.djicdn.com/uploads/sku/covers/31314/small_55e19eff-2d6a-4d75-8e63-b9b5822fd298.png

Just wondering what is the purpose of using more than 1 CDN domain, more parallel downloads?

If so, how many domains I should use?

Answer (score 1):

This is no longer a recommended way to load assets from CDN. Its better to use a single CDN and load as many resources using it as possible so that the HTTP/2 connection can be reused and the page has to create less connections.

Back in the HTTP/1.1 times, it was a common practice to load resources over multiple hosts to parallelize their download. This was a helpful practice at that time and could significantly speed up rich webpages for users with more bandwidth. This technique was called Domain Sharding.

But after HTTP/2, it is no longer required and seen as a bad practice. The above store seems to be built in the HTTP/1.1 era and optimized for the browser of that time.

There is another term "Incidental Domain Sharding" which means web development practices have resulted in developers unnecessarily relying on more and more hosts to deliver their content. For example, sites these days load fonts from Google Fonts, public libraries from some javascript CDN, and host their private content on a private CDN. This requires the browser to open several unnecessary connections that can otherwise be avoided, and prevents browser to avail the HTTP/2 multiplexing. But there are possible solutions like [PageCDN](https://pagecdn.com/about/why) and [EasyFonts](https://pagecdn.com/lib/easyfonts) that collectively can help achieve maximum performance out of the available technologies since they load all the page resources over single CDN.

If you want to see Incidental Domain Sharding in action, have a look at source code of http://www.piston.rs/dyon-tutorial/ They are loading resources over 5 CDNs, and their private content (website CSS and JS files) still need a private CDN.